# Extracting points by multipolygon and having separate point(s) output using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point, extract, multi-polygon

I have a point shapefile that has 1.5 million data points and I want to extract the points that are within in each polygon of a `multipolygon.shp` file and have separate outputs. Let's say there are `32` polygons in the `multipoly` file, so there would be `32` extracted point shapefiles.

Usually I would use the Intersect tool in ArcGIS Pro, but that would return a single output file.

What tool I can use in ArcGIS Pro 3 to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to spatially join the polygons to the points, this assumes the polygons have a unique ID field. If you are using ArcGIS Pro 3 do not use the new Add Spatial Join tool, use the classic Spatial Join tool as this works with the split by attribute tools.

You can then use the Split by Attributes tool to explode out the point dataset into separate datasets, using the unique polygon ID field.

This can be encapsulated in a simple model

[image: Model]

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Thank you for the model, so what would be `fGDB_Scratch` in my case?

Comment: That's the name I give my general working file geodatabase. It must already exist and you can call it what ever you like.

Comment: The model is running really really slow, like it kept on running overnight and it's still stuck at 4% (probably due to the 1.5 million points) and the data being on a server. I have a Core i9 with 14 cores and 64 GB RAM, so is there a way to use like 12 cores in this model to speed up the process?

Comment: What formats are your input datasets, if they are shapefiles then have you added a spatial index to them?

Comment: I just ended up exporting the data to a local SSD (crazy fast) drive and ran the model from there and it took like 5 minutes. Our servers have recently been slow due to Oracle.

Comment: 12 hours to 5 minutes not bad :)